# Jquery- downloading file based on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery /HTML form which the user submits. I pass the form values to a url
 and based on the user form submission an Excel file is downloaded.

I populate the url with the form values and Excel files gets downloaded. example below:

```
http://localhost:8080/Service/getReport?report=pers_fees_report&startDate=20161201&endDate=20161231&programId=&balanceDate=&delivery=stream"
```

I was trying to use ajax but look like Ajax may not be necessary in this scenario.

Is their a way to send the user feedback when the excel file is downloaded or fails to download? is their any examples?

Get the form values

```
$("#submit").on('keypress click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    reportName  = $("#reportName").val();
    start = $("#start").val();
    end = $("#end").val();
    sourceId    = $("#sourceId").val();
    programId   = $("#programId").val();
    sourceId2   = $("#sourceId2").val();
    programId2  = $("#programId2").val();
    balance = $("#balanceDate").val();
    if(reportName !== '' ){
        reportData ="report="+reportName+"&startDate="+start+"&endDate="+end+"&programId="+programId+"&balanceDate="+balance+"&delivery="+stream;
        getExcel(newURL,reportData);
        //Reset form
        // $("form#reportName")[0].reset();
    }
});
```

function getExcel

```
function getExcel(newURL,reportData) {  
    var Report = "http://localhost:8080/Service/getReport?report=pers_fees_report&startDate=20161201&endDate=20161231&programId=&balanceDate=&delivery=stream"
    console.log("reportName " + reportName); 
    console.log("programId " + programId); 
    console.log("dbalanceDatet " + balanceDate); 
    console.log("sourceId " + sourceId); 

    $.ajax({
        url: Report,
        type: "post",
        //data: {report:reportName,startDate:start,endDate:end,programId:programId},
        //data: $('form#reportForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('FAILED to get  JSON from AJAX call' + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta - the link you posted is back to my URL..what is the correct URL?  Thanks

Comment: @user2444394 try this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax